# simple axi lite slave application

Tags: vhdl, vivado, zynq

I am using Vivado 2015.3 and a Zybo board and I am trying to implement a very simple AXI lite IP which recieves a character from the PS and sends back the same value +1.

I just switched from planahead on which the generated vhdl files for the IP were quite simpler (in my opinion) and now I couldn't find any usefull tutorial for this case.

My question is where inside the 2 generated vhdl files (my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI and my_ip_0_v1_0) should I add the "+1"?

Thanks :)

**my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI.vhd :**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI is
generic (
    -- Users to add parameters here

    -- User parameters ends
    -- Do not modify the parameters beyond this line

    -- Width of S_AXI data bus
    C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH  : integer   := 32;
    -- Width of S_AXI address bus
    C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH  : integer   := 4
);
port (
    -- Users to add ports here

    -- User ports ends
    -- Do not modify the ports beyond this line

    -- Global Clock Signal
    S_AXI_ACLK  : in std_logic;
    -- Global Reset Signal. This Signal is Active LOW
    S_AXI_ARESETN   : in std_logic;
    -- Write address (issued by master, acceped by Slave)
    S_AXI_AWADDR    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    -- Write channel Protection type. This signal indicates the
        -- privilege and security level of the transaction, and whether
        -- the transaction is a data access or an instruction access.
    S_AXI_AWPROT    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    -- Write address valid. This signal indicates that the master signaling
        -- valid write address and control information.
    S_AXI_AWVALID   : in std_logic;
    -- Write address ready. This signal indicates that the slave is ready
        -- to accept an address and associated control signals.
    S_AXI_AWREADY   : out std_logic;
    -- Write data (issued by master, acceped by Slave) 
    S_AXI_WDATA : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    -- Write strobes. This signal indicates which byte lanes hold
        -- valid data. There is one write strobe bit for each eight
        -- bits of the write data bus.    
    S_AXI_WSTRB : in std_logic_vector((C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
    -- Write valid. This signal indicates that valid write
        -- data and strobes are available.
    S_AXI_WVALID    : in std_logic;
    -- Write ready. This signal indicates that the slave
        -- can accept the write data.
    S_AXI_WREADY    : out std_logic;
    -- Write response. This signal indicates the status
        -- of the write transaction.
    S_AXI_BRESP : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    -- Write response valid. This signal indicates that the channel
        -- is signaling a valid write response.
    S_AXI_BVALID    : out std_logic;
    -- Response ready. This signal indicates that the master
        -- can accept a write response.
    S_AXI_BREADY    : in std_logic;
    -- Read address (issued by master, acceped by Slave)
    S_AXI_ARADDR    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    -- Protection type. This signal indicates the privilege
        -- and security level of the transaction, and whether the
        -- transaction is a data access or an instruction access.
    S_AXI_ARPROT    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    -- Read address valid. This signal indicates that the channel
        -- is signaling valid read address and control information.
    S_AXI_ARVALID   : in std_logic;
    -- Read address ready. This signal indicates that the slave is
        -- ready to accept an address and associated control signals.
    S_AXI_ARREADY   : out std_logic;
    -- Read data (issued by slave)
    S_AXI_RDATA : out std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    -- Read response. This signal indicates the status of the
        -- read transfer.
    S_AXI_RRESP : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    -- Read valid. This signal indicates that the channel is
        -- signaling the required read data.
    S_AXI_RVALID    : out std_logic;
    -- Read ready. This signal indicates that the master can
        -- accept the read data and response information.
    S_AXI_RREADY    : in std_logic
);
end my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI;

architecture arch_imp of my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI is

-- AXI4LITE signals
signal axi_awaddr   : std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal axi_awready  : std_logic;
signal axi_wready   : std_logic;
signal axi_bresp    : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal axi_bvalid   : std_logic;
signal axi_araddr   : std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal axi_arready  : std_logic;
signal axi_rdata    : std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal axi_rresp    : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal axi_rvalid   : std_logic;

-- Example-specific design signals
-- local parameter for addressing 32 bit / 64 bit C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH
-- ADDR_LSB is used for addressing 32/64 bit registers/memories
-- ADDR_LSB = 2 for 32 bits (n downto 2)
-- ADDR_LSB = 3 for 64 bits (n downto 3)
constant ADDR_LSB  : integer := (C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/32)+ 1;
constant OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS : integer := 1;
------------------------------------------------
---- Signals for user logic register space example
--------------------------------------------------
---- Number of Slave Registers 4
signal slv_reg0 :std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal slv_reg1 :std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal slv_reg2 :std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal slv_reg3 :std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal slv_reg_rden : std_logic;
signal slv_reg_wren : std_logic;
signal reg_data_out :std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal byte_index   : integer;

begin
-- I/O Connections assignments

S_AXI_AWREADY   <= axi_awready;
S_AXI_WREADY    <= axi_wready;
S_AXI_BRESP <= axi_bresp;
S_AXI_BVALID    <= axi_bvalid;
S_AXI_ARREADY   <= axi_arready;
S_AXI_RDATA <= axi_rdata;
S_AXI_RRESP <= axi_rresp;
S_AXI_RVALID    <= axi_rvalid;
-- Implement axi_awready generation
-- axi_awready is asserted for one S_AXI_ACLK clock cycle when both
-- S_AXI_AWVALID and S_AXI_WVALID are asserted. axi_awready is
-- de-asserted when reset is low.

process (S_AXI_ACLK)
begin
  if rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK) then 
    if S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' then
      axi_awready <= '0';
    else
      if (axi_awready = '0' and S_AXI_AWVALID = '1' and S_AXI_WVALID = '1')         then
        -- slave is ready to accept write address when
        -- there is a valid write address and write data
        -- on the write address and data bus. This design 
        -- expects no outstanding transactions. 
        axi_awready <= '1';
      else
        axi_awready <= '0';
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

-- Implement axi_awaddr latching
-- This process is used to latch the address when both 
-- S_AXI_AWVALID and S_AXI_WVALID are valid. 

process (S_AXI_ACLK)
begin
  if rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK) then 
    if S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' then
      axi_awaddr <= (others => '0');
    else
      if (axi_awready = '0' and S_AXI_AWVALID = '1' and S_AXI_WVALID = '1') then
        -- Write Address latching
        axi_awaddr <= S_AXI_AWADDR;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;                   
end process; 

-- Implement axi_wready generation
-- axi_wready is asserted for one S_AXI_ACLK clock cycle when both
-- S_AXI_AWVALID and S_AXI_WVALID are asserted. axi_wready is 
-- de-asserted when reset is low. 

process (S_AXI_ACLK)
begin
  if rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK) then 
    if S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' then
      axi_wready <= '0';
    else
      if (axi_wready = '0' and S_AXI_WVALID = '1' and S_AXI_AWVALID = '1') then
          -- slave is ready to accept write data when 
          -- there is a valid write address and write data
          -- on the write address and data bus. This design 
          -- expects no outstanding transactions.           
          axi_wready <= '1';
      else
        axi_wready <= '0';
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process; 

-- Implement memory mapped register select and write logic generation
-- The write data is accepted and written to memory mapped registers when
-- axi_awready, S_AXI_WVALID, axi_wready and S_AXI_WVALID are asserted. Write strobes are used to
-- select byte enables of slave registers while writing.
-- These registers are cleared when reset (active low) is applied.
-- Slave register write enable is asserted when valid address and data are available
-- and the slave is ready to accept the write address and write data.
slv_reg_wren <= axi_wready and S_AXI_WVALID and axi_awready and S_AXI_AWVALID ;

process (S_AXI_ACLK)
variable loc_addr :std_logic_vector(OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS downto 0); 
begin
  if rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK) then 
    if S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' then
      slv_reg0 <= (others => '0');
      slv_reg1 <= (others => '0');
      slv_reg2 <= (others => '0');
      slv_reg3 <= (others => '0');
    else
      loc_addr := axi_awaddr(ADDR_LSB + OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS downto ADDR_LSB);
      if (slv_reg_wren = '1') then
        case loc_addr is
          when b"00" =>
            for byte_index in 0 to (C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8-1) loop
              if ( S_AXI_WSTRB(byte_index) = '1' ) then
                -- Respective byte enables are asserted as per write strobes                   
                -- slave registor 0
                slv_reg0(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8) <= S_AXI_WDATA(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8);
              end if;
            end loop;
          when b"01" =>
            for byte_index in 0 to (C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8-1) loop
              if ( S_AXI_WSTRB(byte_index) = '1' ) then
                -- Respective byte enables are asserted as per write strobes                   
                -- slave registor 1
                slv_reg1(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8) <= S_AXI_WDATA(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8);
              end if;
            end loop;
          when b"10" =>
            for byte_index in 0 to (C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8-1) loop
              if ( S_AXI_WSTRB(byte_index) = '1' ) then
                -- Respective byte enables are asserted as per write strobes                   
                -- slave registor 2
                slv_reg2(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8) <= S_AXI_WDATA(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8);
              end if;
            end loop;
          when b"11" =>
            for byte_index in 0 to (C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8-1) loop
              if ( S_AXI_WSTRB(byte_index) = '1' ) then
                -- Respective byte enables are asserted as per write strobes                   
                -- slave registor 3
                slv_reg3(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8) <= S_AXI_WDATA(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8);
              end if;
            end loop;
          when others =>
            slv_reg0 <= slv_reg0;
            slv_reg1 <= slv_reg1;
            slv_reg2 <= slv_reg2;
            slv_reg3 <= slv_reg3;
        end case;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;                   
end process; 

-- Implement write response logic generation
-- The write response and response valid signals are asserted by the slave 
-- when axi_wready, S_AXI_WVALID, axi_wready and S_AXI_WVALID are asserted.  
-- This marks the acceptance of address and indicates the status of 
-- write transaction.

process (S_AXI_ACLK)
begin
  if rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK) then 
    if S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' then
      axi_bvalid  <= '0';
      axi_bresp   <= "00"; --need to work more on the responses
    else
      if (axi_awready = '1' and S_AXI_AWVALID = '1' and axi_wready = '1' and S_AXI_WVALID = '1' and axi_bvalid = '0'  ) then
        axi_bvalid <= '1';
        axi_bresp  <= "00"; 
      elsif (S_AXI_BREADY = '1' and axi_bvalid = '1') then   --check if bready is asserted while bvalid is high)
        axi_bvalid <= '0';                                 -- (there is a possibility that bready is always asserted high)
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;                   
end process; 

-- Implement axi_arready generation
-- axi_arready is asserted for one S_AXI_ACLK clock cycle when
-- S_AXI_ARVALID is asserted. axi_awready is 
-- de-asserted when reset (active low) is asserted. 
-- The read address is also latched when S_AXI_ARVALID is 
-- asserted. axi_araddr is reset to zero on reset assertion.

process (S_AXI_ACLK)
begin
  if rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK) then 
    if S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' then
      axi_arready <= '0';
      axi_araddr  <= (others => '1');
    else
      if (axi_arready = '0' and S_AXI_ARVALID = '1') then
        -- indicates that the slave has acceped the valid read address
        axi_arready <= '1';
        -- Read Address latching 
        axi_araddr  <= S_AXI_ARADDR;           
      else
        axi_arready <= '0';
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;                   
end process; 

-- Implement axi_arvalid generation
-- axi_rvalid is asserted for one S_AXI_ACLK clock cycle when both 
-- S_AXI_ARVALID and axi_arready are asserted. The slave registers 
-- data are available on the axi_rdata bus at this instance. The 
-- assertion of axi_rvalid marks the validity of read data on the 
-- bus and axi_rresp indicates the status of read transaction.axi_rvalid 
-- is deasserted on reset (active low). axi_rresp and axi_rdata are 
-- cleared to zero on reset (active low).  
process (S_AXI_ACLK)
begin
  if rising_edge(S_AXI_ACLK) then
    if S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' then
      axi_rvalid <= '0';
      axi_rresp  <= "00";
    else
      if (axi_arready = '1' and S_AXI_ARVALID = '1' and axi_rvalid = '0') then
        -- Valid read data is available at the read data bus
        axi_rvalid <= '1';
        axi_rresp  <= "00"; -- 'OKAY' response
      elsif (axi_rvalid = '1' and S_AXI_RREADY = '1') then
        -- Read data is accepted by the master
        axi_rvalid <= '0';
      end if;            
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

-- Implement memory mapped register select and read logic generation
-- Slave register read enable is asserted when valid address is available
-- and the slave is ready to accept the read address.
slv_reg_rden <= axi_arready and S_AXI_ARVALID and (not axi_rvalid) ;

process (slv_reg0, slv_reg1, slv_reg2, slv_reg3, axi_araddr, S_AXI_ARESETN, slv_reg_rden)
variable loc_addr :std_logic_vector(OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS downto 0);
begin
    -- Address decoding for reading registers
    loc_addr := axi_araddr(ADDR_LSB + OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS downto ADDR_LSB);
    case loc_addr is
      when b"00" =>
        reg_data_out <= slv_reg0;
      when b"01" =>
        reg_data_out <= slv_reg1;
      when b"10" =>
        reg_data_out <= slv_reg2;
      when b"11" =>
        reg_data_out <= slv_reg3;
      when others =>
        reg_data_out  <= (others => '0');
    end case;
end process; 

-- Output register or memory read data
process( S_AXI_ACLK ) is
begin
  if (rising_edge (S_AXI_ACLK)) then
    if ( S_AXI_ARESETN = '0' ) then
      axi_rdata  <= (others => '0');
    else
      if (slv_reg_rden = '1') then
        -- When there is a valid read address (S_AXI_ARVALID) with 
        -- acceptance of read address by the slave (axi_arready), 
        -- output the read dada 
        -- Read address mux
          axi_rdata <= reg_data_out;     -- register read data
      end if;   
    end if;
  end if;
end process;


-- Add user logic here

-- User logic ends

end arch_imp;
```

**my_ip_0_v1_0.vhd :**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity my_ip_0_v1_0 is
generic (
    -- Users to add parameters here

    -- User parameters ends
    -- Do not modify the parameters beyond this line


    -- Parameters of Axi Slave Bus Interface S00_AXI
    C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH    : integer   := 32;
    C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH    : integer   := 4
);
port (
    -- Users to add ports here

    -- User ports ends
    -- Do not modify the ports beyond this line


    -- Ports of Axi Slave Bus Interface S00_AXI
    s00_axi_aclk    : in std_logic;
    s00_axi_aresetn : in std_logic;
    s00_axi_awaddr  : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    s00_axi_awprot  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    s00_axi_awvalid : in std_logic;
    s00_axi_awready : out std_logic;
    s00_axi_wdata   : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    s00_axi_wstrb   : in std_logic_vector((C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
    s00_axi_wvalid  : in std_logic;
    s00_axi_wready  : out std_logic;
    s00_axi_bresp   : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    s00_axi_bvalid  : out std_logic;
    s00_axi_bready  : in std_logic;
    s00_axi_araddr  : in std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    s00_axi_arprot  : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    s00_axi_arvalid : in std_logic;
    s00_axi_arready : out std_logic;
    s00_axi_rdata   : out std_logic_vector(C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    s00_axi_rresp   : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    s00_axi_rvalid  : out std_logic;
    s00_axi_rready  : in std_logic
);
end my_ip_0_v1_0;

architecture arch_imp of my_ip_0_v1_0 is

-- component declaration
component my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI is
    generic (
    C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH  : integer   := 32;
    C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH  : integer   := 4
    );
    port (
    S_AXI_ACLK  : in std_logic;
    S_AXI_ARESETN   : in std_logic;
    S_AXI_AWADDR    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    S_AXI_AWPROT    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    S_AXI_AWVALID   : in std_logic;
    S_AXI_AWREADY   : out std_logic;
    S_AXI_WDATA : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    S_AXI_WSTRB : in std_logic_vector((C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
    S_AXI_WVALID    : in std_logic;
    S_AXI_WREADY    : out std_logic;
    S_AXI_BRESP : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    S_AXI_BVALID    : out std_logic;
    S_AXI_BREADY    : in std_logic;
    S_AXI_ARADDR    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    S_AXI_ARPROT    : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    S_AXI_ARVALID   : in std_logic;
    S_AXI_ARREADY   : out std_logic;
    S_AXI_RDATA : out std_logic_vector(C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    S_AXI_RRESP : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    S_AXI_RVALID    : out std_logic;
    S_AXI_RREADY    : in std_logic
    );
end component my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI;

begin

-- Instantiation of Axi Bus Interface S00_AXI
my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI_inst : my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI
generic map (
    C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH  => C_S00_AXI_DATA_WIDTH,
    C_S_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH  => C_S00_AXI_ADDR_WIDTH
)
port map (
    S_AXI_ACLK  => s00_axi_aclk,
    S_AXI_ARESETN   => s00_axi_aresetn,
    S_AXI_AWADDR    => s00_axi_awaddr,
    S_AXI_AWPROT    => s00_axi_awprot,
    S_AXI_AWVALID   => s00_axi_awvalid,
    S_AXI_AWREADY   => s00_axi_awready,
    S_AXI_WDATA => s00_axi_wdata,
    S_AXI_WSTRB => s00_axi_wstrb,
    S_AXI_WVALID    => s00_axi_wvalid,
    S_AXI_WREADY    => s00_axi_wready,
    S_AXI_BRESP => s00_axi_bresp,
    S_AXI_BVALID    => s00_axi_bvalid,
    S_AXI_BREADY    => s00_axi_bready,
    S_AXI_ARADDR    => s00_axi_araddr,
    S_AXI_ARPROT    => s00_axi_arprot,
    S_AXI_ARVALID   => s00_axi_arvalid,
    S_AXI_ARREADY   => s00_axi_arready,
    S_AXI_RDATA => s00_axi_rdata,
    S_AXI_RRESP => s00_axi_rresp,
    S_AXI_RVALID    => s00_axi_rvalid,
    S_AXI_RREADY    => s00_axi_rready
);

-- Add user logic here

-- User logic ends

end arch_imp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_ip_0_v1_0.vhd` instantiates `my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI.vhd` so `my_ip_0_v1_0.vhd` is the top level and you should (as the comments say) put your custom code in `my_ip_0_v1_0_S00_AXI.vhd`. But things are a bit more complex: in Zynq cores the PS communicates with the PL using the AXI bus protocol. So, if you want to implement your +1 module, the most complex part will be the AXI protocol (5 channels, handshaking...) And the automatically generated wrappers are overcomplicated. You should probably consider having a look at the AXI lite specification and implementing the minimal AXI lite compatible hardware.

Anyway, assuming you want to store your character at address 0 (`b"00"`), in least significant byte position and you increment upon write, you can add your custom code in the *memory mapped register select and write logic generation* process:

```
when b"00" =>
  for byte_index in 0 to (C_S_AXI_DATA_WIDTH/8-1) loop
    if ( S_AXI_WSTRB(byte_index) = '1' ) then
      if byte_index = 0 then
        slv_reg0(7 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(S_AXI_WDATA(7 downto 0)) + 1);
      else
        slv_reg0(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8) <= S_AXI_WDATA(byte_index*8+7 downto byte_index*8);
      end if;
    end if;
  end loop;
```

Writing any 32 bits value at address 0 of the address space of your peripheral shall store the 24 most significant bits unmodified and the 8 least significant bits incremented (with automatic wrapping around `0xff`). Of course, to notice this, you must read back at address 0.

Comment: it's all generated by vivado. It should be quite intuitive where to add data to be sent to PS

Comment: More or less. But the generated template implements four 32-bits registers. You must at least decide which of the four 32-bits registers will store the character sent by the PS, at which position in the 32-bits and when the +1 operation takes place (upon read or upon write). I update my answer to give you a hint in one of all these configurations.

Comment: not doing anything at all....I am writing something to an address and then when I read from it I get the same thing...every single time

Comment: What address and on top of what software stack? If you are running a bare metal application you just need to find out at which physical base address your component has been mapped by Vivado (unless you specified this address yourself, in which case you know it). If you are running on top of a Linux kernel things are a bit more complex because you are working in a virtual address space.

Comment: from #include "xparameters.h" I can use the XPAR_MY_IP_0_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR on which I can Xil_Out32 and Xil_In32.

Comment: Sorry but debugging your problem across Stack Overflow is much more difficult than using a JTAG probe. Don't you have a better way to observe what happens and why? Did you check that the address space of your peripheral is not cacheable? Are you running on top of the Linux kernel? What is the value of `XPAR_MY_IP_0_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR`? Did you look at these `Xil_Out32` and `Xil_In32` primitives and understood what they do? Did you try to add a debug output signal to your peripheral and wire it to a LED (e.g. the LSB of slv_reg0)?